# Chrome showing white screen and opens in small window

Tags: google-chrome, white-screen

Chrome was working fine and till yesterday. But now when click to open chrome it opens like this screenshot. There is no menu, no tab, just blank screen. I searched everywhere but got nothing.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I updated chrome 4 days back (sudo apt update   and then sudo apt upgrade), so it is latest version.
I have tried to uninstall and then install it but again it is same.

[image]

Comment: Is your system fully updated? What version of Ubuntu? What version of Chrome? Please [edit] your question and add more specific information about your system.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post

Comment: Please, create a new Ubuntu user and try to run Chrome under that user. If it runs OK, then probably there is a problem with Chrome config data of your current user. You can rename the `~/.config/google-chrome` directory of the current user and retry.

Comment: Chrome is my defaul browser, so I tried to open it by hyperlink (basicly clicked on link in pdf) and this worked and chrome opened but now there is a new problem. I cannot use keyboard in chrome. Just mouse and touchpad click. Please help, I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: Interesting. I have a [similar issue with the gnome control center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378343/gnome-control-center-show-up-white) on just one computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This answer will be incomplete without your feedback @John.*

---

Click GNOME **Settings¹ → Users → Unlock → Add User...** and create a new "standard user".

Log out from your current user and log in with the "new user". Try **Google Chrome** under that user.

**If it runs OK, then there is a problem with your "normal user"'s configuration.**

You can log out from the "new user" and log back in to your "normal user". Delete the "new user" (by deleting its files too).

In your "normal user" run:

```
$ pgrep -ax chrome
 [ Ensure no output is produced; otherwise re-log in and retry ]
$ cd ~/.config
$ mv google-chrome google-chrome_OLD
```

Retry launching **Google Chrome**. Note: This way *you will lose all the configurations, history, bookmarks, cookies etc*. If you want them back, you can restore some data from the `..._OLD` directory step by step.

---

<sub>¹ Command-line for GNOME **Settings** is `gnome-control-center`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it worked for me.[ENV: Windows11+Ubuntu-22.04(WSL2)]

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
export DISPLAY=:0
```